# Python Script: Set Value for Modifier manually

Tags: python, scripting

Does anyone know if it's possible to write a python code that enables you to manually set individual parameters for modifiers? For example:

## Solidify-Modifier to set the wall thickness

```
bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='SOLIDIFY')
bpy.context.object.modifiers["Solidify"].thickness = 0.4 #[mm]
bpy.context.object.modifiers["Solidify"].use_even_offset = True
bpy.context.object.modifiers["Solidify"].use_quality_normals = True
bpy.context.object.modifiers["Solidify"].use_rim = True
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA', modifier="Solidify")
```

Is it possible to not set the value for the wall thickness in the code itself, but rather have the user type a value manually? This is only part of the code for a mesh-reparing Add-On I need for 3D Printing. And the wall thickness will depend on the structure. Any suggestions are appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Invoke a popup dialog.**

[image]

Test script to invoke a properties dialog to "manually" type in a thickness value, then add and apply a thickness modifier to a mesh object.  I've called the operator "Add Thickness", hit <kbd>F3</kbd> to bring up search.

Notice I've used the API method `ob.modifiers.new(name, type)` rather than the add modifier operator.

```
import bpy

class WM_OT_myop(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "wm.myop"
    bl_label = "Add thickness"
    # annotations in 2.8
    thickness : bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Thickness", default=0.4)

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return (context.active_object is not None and context.object.type == 'MESH')

    def execute(self, context):
        ob = context.object
        m = ob.modifiers.new("Solidify", type='SOLIDIFY')
        m.thickness = self.thickness
        m.use_even_offset = True
        m.use_quality_normals = True
        m.use_rim = True
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA', modifier=m.name)
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(WM_OT_myop)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(WM_OT_myop)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.wm.myop('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

Note this example is for 2.8.  To make it for prior, change

```
thickness : bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Thickness", default=0.4)
```

to

```
thickness = bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Thickness", default=0.4)
```

and use the <kbd>spacebar</kbd> to bring up the operator search.

Note: I could have simply pasted your code into the execute method of the operator. This is why (on my soapbox) I strongly recommend using a context variable, eg a line `context = bpy.context` at the top of test code (*not to paste if context is defined elsewhere*). For example if the context is overridden in an operator the context passed to execute may not be `bpy.context`